# Stone-Weierstrass theorem for $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, approximation-theory

By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, we know that any $X$ compact with $A\subseteq C(X,\mathbb{R})$ subalgebra, we know that $A$ is then dense. However, is it true for the case where we have $\mathbb{R}^m$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$? For example, is it true that the set of polynomials from $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ to $Y\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ dense in the set $C(X,Y)$?

Comment: What do you mean by an algebra contained in $C(X,\mathbb R^{m})$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think it is just similar to the algebra in $C(X,\mathbb{R})$, where it is closed under addition, multiplication, and scalar multiplication of functions?

Comment: How do you multiply such functions?

Comment: @PaulFrost Oh... Right, I cannot simply multiply two functions given that such function maps to $\mathbb{R}^m$... Then is it possible to prove this statement without the aid of using algebra?

Comment: In Stone-Weierstrass’ theorem are imposed conditions on $A$. For instance, functions from $A$ separate points from $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: There is an obvious homeomorphism

$$h : C(X,\mathbb R^m) \to C(X, \mathbb R)^m ,$$
where $C(X, \mathbb R)^m$ is the product of $m$ copies of $C(X, \mathbb R)$. Thus each dense subset $D \subset C(X, \mathbb R)$ gives a dense subset $h^{-1}(D^m)$ of $C(X,\mathbb R^m)$.

Comment: So we have:
$Poly(X,\mathbb{R}^m) =Poly(X,\mathbb{R})\times\cdots\times Poly(X,\mathbb{R}) \subseteq\text{ (and dense in) } C(X,\mathbb{R})^m = C(X,\mathbb{R}^m)$ 
So $Poly(X,\mathbb{R}^m)$ dense in $C(X,\mathbb{R}^m)$. Am I correct here?

Answer (score 1):

Like in Stone-Weierstrass’ theorem, we assume that $C(X,Y)$ has the topology of uniform convergence.

The answer is negative even when $X=Y=\Bbb R$, because we cannot approximate an exponent $e^x$, which grows faster than any polynomial. On the other hand, for natural $n$ and $m$, a set of *analytic* functions is uniformly dense is $C(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^m)$. This is a corollary of much more general result of Kurzweil, see [Ku]. For a short survey and recent advances in this topic see our paper [MR].

On the other hand, in 1885 Weierstrass showed that for each natural $n$ and each *compact* subset $X$ of $\Bbb R^n$,  any function $f\in C(X,\Bbb R)$ can be uniformly approximated by restrictions on $X$ of polynomials on $\Bbb R^n$. By the way, this is the first known result on uniform approximation of continuous functions. We can extend it to $C(X,\Bbb R^m)$, following Paul Frost’s [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871847/stone-weierstrass-theorem-for-c-mathbbrn-mathbbrm/3871924#3871924).

*References*

[Ku] Kurzweil J. *[On approximation in real Banach spaces](http://eudml.org/doc/216828)*, Studia Mathematica **14** (1954), 214–231.

[MR] Mytrofanov M., Ravsky A. [A note on approximation of continuous functions on normed spaces](https://journals.pnu.edu.ua/index.php/cmp/article/view/3890),  Carpathian mathematical publications (2020) **12**:1 107–110.